# Saving login password by browser when using dynamically generated content

Tags: java, html, gwt, authentication, smartgwt

I have a web application and this application's UI is written in SmartGWT. If  there is no record in the session, the user is requested to log in via form generated by SmartGWT (DynamicForm).

How can I achieve the common browser functionality to save the user password in order to be able to not to fill the password over and over again?

I guess it should work out-of-the-box for static html form, but what about dynamically generated content?

Comment: using cookies is not an option ?

Comment: It probably is, but I don't want to add any unnecessary logic (more code -> more bugs :]). How to make a browser to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this could be a solution http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ#auto-complete_and_GWT

Answer (score 1):

GWT has a nice support for Cookies, there is no big effort needed :

```
 public void onModuleLoad() {

    // Retrieve the cookie value
    // Returns : the cookie's value, or null if the cookie doesn't exist
    String value = Cookies.getCookie("CookieName");

    // Set cookie value
    Cookies.setCookie("CookieName","ANYVALUE");
}
```

You can then use the Cookies to store any information you want about the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care much about security, you could use local storage:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp